# How do I dynamically add pylons apps to a uwsgi process on nginx with UWSGI_SCRIPT?

Tags: nginx, pylons, dynamic, uwsgi

I have successfully deployed a single pylons app on nginx + uwsgi using:

```
uwsgi --paste config:/var/www/sites/helloworld/development.ini --socket :3031 -H /var/www/virtualenv
```

However I am using nginx to virtual host 3 sites.

Based on [this tutorial](http://lithostech.com/2010/04/serving-up-python-with-the-quickness/) and the uwsgi/wiki/DynamicApps page from main uwsgi site on unbit, I can add apps dynamically to uwsgi without having to create 3 separate uwsgi init.d scripts for 3 master processes over 3 separate ports.

My nginx virtual host configurations are setup just like in the tutorial, but I am having a problem with the UWSGI_SCRIPT value.  I have it set to app.wsgi (which is located at /var/www/sites/helloworld/app.wsgi). The script code is:

```
from paste.deploy import loadapp
wsgi_app = loadapp('config:/var/www/sites/helloworld/development.ini')
```

But I can't find any straightforward info about this script.  Is it suppose to be named app_wsgi.py instead or different code altogether? And where is it supposed to be located?
When I visit the site I get: "uWSGI Error - wsgi application not found", then I see this in my uwsgi.log:

```
interpreter for app 0 initialized.
ImportError: No module named app.wsgi
[pid: 7287|app: -1|req: -1/24] XXX.XXX.XXX.133 () {48 vars in 782 bytes} [Fri Aug 13 18:41:22 2010] GET /page/view/0 => generated 46 bytes in 8 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 63 bytes (0 async switches on async core 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me like this:

```
location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:5000;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_PYHOME /home/don/dev/envs/pylons; #this is my virtualenv
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_CHDIR /home/don/dev/envs/pylons/apps/helloworld; #so app.py can be found
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT app; # app.py: where i put loadapp code
        uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME ""; # this line is needed, don't know what it means
}
```

then start uwsgi with --vhost [--no-site], remember to set debug to false in your development.ini if you start uwsgi with master and worker processes, besides rename your app name from wsgi_app to application, that's what uwsgi is going to look for